leetcode graphql query. Deployment problem
I'm trying to create leetcode user statss application. But when I try it on localhost it is working properly without any issue but when I deployed it on vercel it and try to find a user's profile it is giving me error 404.
please tell me where is the issue. I'm new in this please review my code and tell me where I went wrong

const express = require('express');
const cors = require('cors');

const app = express();
app.use(cors({
    origin: '*' // Adjust the CORS policy as needed
}));

const query = 
  `query getUserProfile($username: String!) {
    allQuestionsCount {
      difficulty
      count
    }
    matchedUser(username: $username) {
      contributions {
        points
      }
      profile {
        reputation
        ranking
      }
      submissionCalendar
      submitStats {
        acSubmissionNum {
          difficulty
          count
          submissions
        }
        totalSubmissionNum {
          difficulty
          count
          submissions
        }
      }
    }
    recentSubmissionList(username: $username) {
      title
      titleSlug
      timestamp
      statusDisplay
      lang
      __typename
    }
    matchedUserStats: matchedUser(username: $username) {
      submitStats: submitStatsGlobal {
        acSubmissionNum {
          difficulty
          count
          submissions
          __typename
        }
        totalSubmissionNum {
          difficulty
          count
          submissions
          __typename
        }
        __typename
      }
    }
  }`
;

const formatData = (data) => {
  return {
    totalSolved: data.matchedUserStats.submitStats.acSubmissionNum[0].count,
    totalSubmissions: data.matchedUser.submitStats.totalSubmissionNum,
    totalQuestions: data.allQuestionsCount[0].count,
    easySolved: data.matchedUser.submitStats.acSubmissionNum[1].count,
    totalEasy: data.allQuestionsCount[1].count,
    mediumSolved: data.matchedUser.submitStats.acSubmissionNum[2].count,
    totalMedium: data.allQuestionsCount[2].count,
    hardSolved: data.matchedUser.submitStats.acSubmissionNum[3].count,
    totalHard: data.allQuestionsCount[3].count,
    ranking: data.matchedUser.profile.ranking,
    contributionPoint: data.matchedUser.contributions.points,
    reputation: data.matchedUser.profile.reputation,
    submissionCalendar: JSON.parse(data.matchedUser.submissionCalendar),
    recentSubmissions: data.recentSubmissionList,
    matchedUserStats: data.matchedUser.submitStats,
  };
};

app.get('/:id', (req, res) => {
  const user = req.params.id;
  fetch('https://leetcode.com/graphql', {
    method: 'POST',
    headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      'Referer': 'https://leetcode.com',
    },
    body: JSON.stringify({ query, variables: { username: user } }),
  })
    .then((result) => result.json())
    .then((data) => {
      if (data.errors) {
        res.send({ data });
      } else {
        res.send(formatData(data.data));
      }
    })
    .catch((err) => {
      console.error('Error:', err);
      res.status(500).send(err);
    });
});

// Start the backend server
app.listen(4000, () => {
  console.log('LeetCode Backend is running on port 4000');
});

